# Dyadic distribution of $0/1$ permanents

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, random-matrices, perfect-matchings, permanent

Fix reals $a,b\in(1,2)$ satisfying $1<b<a<ab<2$.

> What fraction of $0/1$ matrices of dimensions $n\times n$ have permanents
> in $[b2^m,a2^m]$ at some $m\in\{0,1,2,\dots,\lfloor\log_2n!\rfloor\}$?
>
> Is it at least $\frac1{p(n)}$ at a fixed polynomial $p(n)$ whose coefficients and degree are independent of $n$?